# Can I make git-svn handle svn:eol-style?

Tags: git, git-svn

A lot of svn repositories require new files to have an svn:eol-style attribute. Is there any way to ensure that this happens with git-svn ?

Answer (score 12):

You can try setting autoproperties ([[1](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch07s02.html#svn-ch-7-sect-2.4)][[2](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch07.html#svn-ch-7-sect-1.3.2)]) in subversion config. It will ensure that during the add operation of new files svn:eol-style is set properly.

AFAIU git-svn is just using svn in inner workings, and it should load the subversion configuration, and set auto-props for new files.

Ok, I tested it, it works.

Example .subversion/config:

```
[miscellany]
enable-auto-props = yes

[auto-props]
*.cpp = svn:keywords=Id Revision;svn:eol-style=native
*.cs = svn:keywords=Id Revision;svn:eol-style=native
```

Comment: But be careful: in my experience, `git-svn` will set the `svn:eol-style=native` attribute on commit, as you describe, but will *not* actually convert the committed files to LF line endings before committing.  So, any CRLF line endings will be committed to the subversion repo intact, but subversion expects all `svn:eol-style=native` attributed files to be stored with LF line endings.  The end result is that the first time someone edits and commits such a file from a subversion working copy, the diff will include CRLF to LF conversion.

Answer (score 8):

[@silk's answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2128873/470844) is only a partial solution.  A complete solution also includes configuring git to convert CRLF to LF on commit.  So, in addition to what @silk suggests, you should also do:

```
git config --global core.autocrlf input
git config --global core.safecrlf warn
```

Or:

```
git config --global core.safecrlf warn
git config --global core.attributesfile ~/.gitattributes
echo '* text=auto' >> ~/.gitattributes
```

Explanation:

In my experience, `git-svn` will set the `svn:eol-style=native` attribute on commit, as @silk describes, but will *not* actually convert the committed files to LF line endings before committing.  So, any CRLF line endings will be committed to the subversion repo intact, but subversion expects all `svn:eol-style=native` attributed files to be stored with LF line endings.  The end result is that the first time someone edits and commits such a file from a subversion working copy, the diff will include CRLF to LF conversion.

So, a complete solution should include forcing git to convert files to LF line endings before committing.  You can do this by setting `core.autocrlf=input`, which means "convert all CRLF to LF on commit, but don't do the reverse conversion on checkout", and `core.safecrlf=warn` or `core.safecrlf=true`, which will warn or stop you when you try to commit a file with CRLF line endings.  The `autocrlf` setting will ensure these CRLFs get converted, so the `safecrlf=true` is probably excessive. See `git help config`.

Alternatively, you can use git attributes to force the conversion, by setting `text=auto` on all files. To do this globally, you need to specify an attributes file in `core.attributesfile`.  See `git help attributes`.

Comment: One more thing: with these configurations, committed files will retain any CRLF line endings in your git-svn working copy until you check them out again.  If you're on *nix and want LF line endings, then you can force the re-checkout by switching to a branch that doesn't contain the CRLF files and then switching back again.  Alternatively, you can use `dos2unix` to convert the line endings, and then `git add` the files; no `git commit` is necessary because the LF line endings are expected.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using [SubGit](http://subgit.com/).

From the very first builds it supports proper Subversion properties to .gitattributes/.gitignore conversion (and vice versa). Amongst other things that includes svn:eol-style and 'eol', svn:mime-type and 'text', svn:ignore and .gitignore conversion.

SubGit is a server-side solution — one has to install it into Subversion repository. After that one can use any Subversion or Git client to send changes into this repository. Please refer to [SubGit documenration](http://subgit.com/documentation/) to get more details. In general it's fairly easy to use it:

1. Generate SubGit configuration file:

   ```
   $ subgit configure svn_repos
   ```
2. Adjust svn_repos/conf/subgit.conf file as needed to specify Git repository location, branches & tags layout, etc.
3. Finish the installation:

   ```
   $ subgit install svn_repos
   ```

At this moment SubGit converts all the revisions from your Subversion repository to Git repository. Then it installs its custom hooks to be triggered by incoming modifications. This way SubGit continuously converts Subversion revisions on every svn commit and Git commits on every git push.

SubGit is a commercial project, but it's free for small teams, open-source and academic projects. And I'm one of SubGit developers.

Comment: This is a perfectly reasonable answer, but please disclose your association with the SubGit project, http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior